# Add new line to print column output in python for csv

Tags: python, csv

**I am fairly new to python and am trying to determine the best way to do this. I have the below code.**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
    for (k,v) in row.items():
        columns[k].append(v)

print(columns['Created'])
print(columns['Person'])
print(columns['Comment'])
```

**I am running it against the below CSV file output.**

```
Created,UnwantedData,Person,Bogus,Comment
4-15-17,test,Chad,w,There is an update
4-16-17,for,Marlon,x,There is no update
4-17-17,this ,Kevin,y,I have reviewed the files
4-18-17,issue,Dan,z,I hate this place.
```

**I only want to print the Created, Person, and Comment sections, however I am getting the below.**

```
['4-15-17', '4-16-17', '4-17-17', '4-18-17']
['Chad', 'Marlon', 'Kevin', 'Dan']]
['There is an update ', 'There is no update', 'I have reviewed the files ', 'I hate this place. ']
```

**I am trying to get the output to looks something like this by adding a new line between each time the output is printed, like so.**

```
4-15-17   
Chad   
There is an update     

4-16-17
Marlon
There is no update

4-17-17
Kevin
I have reviewed the files

4-18-17 
Dan
I hate this place.
```

**Anything would be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest an alternative approach where you simply create a new list of entries with the `dict`s are simply filtered to only contain the required keys.

```
import csv
wanted = ('Created', 'Person', 'Comment')

with open('test.csv') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)

    result = []
    for row in rdr:
        result.append({k: v for k, v in row.items() if k in wanted})

for r in result:
    print(r['Created'])
    print(r['Person'])
    print(r['Comment'])
    print('')
```

If you wish to use your existing code, simply use `zip` to rejoin the items from each list.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)

params = [columns['Created'], columns['Person'], columns['Comment']]
for cre, pers, cmt in zip(*params):
    print(cre)
    print(pers)
    print(cmt)
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print `columns['Created']` you are printing everything stored in the Created column. Instead you simply need to iterate through each item in the column.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k, v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)

for i in xrange(len(columns['Created'])):
    print(columns['Created'][i])
    print(columns['Person'][i])
    print(columns['Comment'][i] + "\n")
```

The "\n" will cause a new line to be printed after the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve the result in a single iteration. And It will save the time.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row_dict in reader:
        print "%s\n%s\n\n" % (row_dict['Created'], row_dict["Person"], row_dict['Comment'])
```